Angular DI for standalone components with importing module on parent component and child component (NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError)
Given the following structure:

a parent standalone component named AppComponent
a child standalone component called TableComponent, which should be a wrapper for a generic table

TableComponent internally uses the Table from primeng (imported from TableModule).
AppComponent needs some directives from TableModule (for example the non standalone directive SelectableRow from TableModule).
If putting everything together I get the following error:

ERROR NullInjectorError:
R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_Table -> _Table ->
_Table]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for _Table!

I don't get why this runtime error occurs.
If adding
providers: [Table, TableService]

to one of both components, the error disappears, but it seems now there are two instances of Table around.
See live at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u7h2az?file=src%2Ftable%2Ftable.interfaces.ts
Any way I can fix the missing dependency?

The pSelectableRow is requiring the Table service through dependency injection, as seen in the below code:
table.ts:3592 - primeng source code
constructor(
    public dt: Table,
    public tableService: TableService,
    private el: ElementRef
) {

But we are using it in the root app component, which is inside an ng-template, here the pSelectableRow is looking for table, which is not present, the table has to be a direct parent to the pSelectableRow, to avoid this error.
The fix for this issue, is to move all directive using elements inside the table component, and keep only the td as inputs to the table component.
<app-table [value]="people" [rows]="people.length" dataKey="id" [headers]="headers">
  <ng-template #bodyTemplate let-person>
      <td>{{person.id}}</td>
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.age}}</td>
  </ng-template>
</app-table>

Then we can pass this as an input to the table component.
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
  <tr [pSelectableRow]="item">
    <ng-template
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="bodyTemplate() ?? null"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"
    >
    </ng-template>
  </tr>
</ng-template>

Stackblitz Demo

Yep, that is a valid workaround, but there are other scenarios where I need to access stuff from TableModule from within the ng-template. Is there any way I can forward the a already initialized dependency (Table service) to the child component? Or can I tie those dependencies together ensuring only one service is initialized (maybe with module structure)?

@kerosene you can raise a github issue with the exact scenario, on primeng github page, to get their opinion, you can try wrapping it inside ngIf, but I use the above method in my answer, it works great for using the same table for multiple row configurations
